# Agrupar Webs independientes en una sola WEB tipo FRAME

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, css

Tengo 3 plantillas webs diferentes cada una con sus respectivos assets (css,js,etc.). Lo que quiero es unirlas en una sola, estaba probando con frames pero no me resulta porque parte la ventana. Intente con PHP guardando cada web en una variable con una función propia de PHP llamada file_get_contents y luego imprimirlos una por otra sucesivamente, sin embargo cuando lo pruebo se distorsionan y confunden los códigos de los assets y la web se me muestra muy diferentes desordenada.

Ayuda por favor, se que esto es algo muy fácil para muchos, sin embargo tengo un cliente que se le ocurrió de 3 templates diferentes y bueno !!

Comment: Basicamente, si no queres utilizar frames la unica solucion es revisando al 100% los 3 proyectos y asegurandote que no usan ni las mismas clases ni los mismos ids y que todo el codigo javascript incluido en cada sitio no altera el de alguno de los otros 2. La idea es algo ridicula, se supone que ademas de lograr esto deberias poder navegar por los 3 sitios embebidos? son sitios estaticos o ademas tienen programacion?

Comment: Lo más probable es que te tire el error de dominio cruzado.

Answer (score 0):

Ensambla todo en un solo html, referenciando todo desde el html a cada carpeta o archivo de css diferentes para que cada diseño de cada una de las 3 webs se vea en cada parte, donde tu quieres, añadiendo lo correspondiente en el html.
Lo que quieres hacer es un poco complicado y arriesgado, porque tienes que tener en cuenta de que a lo mejor una de las 3 webs es responsive y las otras no. Tendrás que revisar todo el código para ver que medidas presenta cada diseño. 
No te recomiendo para nada que hagas eso con iframes, o truquillos raros porque los navegadores y los dispositivos se pueden volver locos interpretando lo que has hecho.

Espero ayudarte con mi respuesta.
**Aunque es una pregunta demasiado amplia y puede que te la quieran cerrar.**

Comment: Lo hice; sin embargo, se siguen mezclando los etilos entre todos los Assets. No sé que estoy haciendo mal quizás, aquí te paso el enlace a ver si podrías decirme en que estoy fallando o no sé. Enlace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzviXt7qjYtTDRSN1JCWmhDcWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no soy muy partidario, la etiqueta `<iframe>` podría ayudarte en lo que necesitas, aunque he visto que has intentado utilizar frames, no se si te referias a esto, pero te permitiria cargar cada web y sus correspondientes assets sin que se mezclen.

Aunque como ha dicho @Marc habria que analizar cada web, si metes una responsive en un ifrmae muy pequeño se te mostraria en formato movil, por lo que habría que analizarlo previamente.

Manda algun trozo de código si no te funciona, a ver si entre todos vemos que te puede estar pasando.

Saludos!

Comment: Ya he cambiado de nombres a las carpetas anteriormente, sin embargo las distorsiones de estilos y Assets siguen iguales, además intente ccon los iframes pero parte la web en 2 demasiado pequeño. A ver si pueden ayudarme con este problema que lo estado intentando pero no consigo resultados. enlace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzviXt7qjYtTDRSN1JCWmhDcWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Buenas @Jsuola, lo que pides es facil pero muy tedioso, por lo que he podido ver en el codigo, estas intentado unificar partes de dos templates distintos, que ademas comparten bastantes class. En mi opinion deberias buscar las clases de la parte del header(ya que es la mas corta) y moverlas al main.css del de cuerpo y organizarlo, porque aunque lo metas en iframes, tendrias que implementar la navegacion del iframe header, para que navegara en el de cuerpo. Y ademas, ambos css estan de manera responsive, provocando un desastre total en dispositivos moviles.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1tWzWbhOQLAM19STGVobWQzbG8?usp=sharing, esto es lo mas parecido que podrias obtener con iframes y no funciona como esperas seguramente. Te recomiendo mover las clases al main css de cuerpo